# Notification Content Extension not displaying custom UI or actions on iPad running 10.3.3

Tags: ios, ipad, notifications, ios10

I have an app, configured for push notifications.

I have a notification service extension and 2 notification content extensions. Notification gets received by the service and it figures out which category to show it. I have custom view controllers for both content extensions, hiding the system default. And 4 actions for each category.

These notifications work and display properly on iPhones running iOS 10-11 and iPads running iOS 11. However, when received on an iPad (4th gen) running 10.3.3 - the notification goes through the service extension, determines the correct category, and then is displayed with a system UI, not my custom controller, and only 2 out of the 4 actions for that notification category are provided. The actions are also presented in-line in the system notification UI, instead of cascading vertically below the notification like it would normally.

I am at a loss, and reaching for the stars here hoping someone has had a similar issue.

iPad running iOS 10.3.3
[image: iPad iOS 10.3.3]

iPad running iOS 11
[image: iPad iOS 11]

Comment: i have  all most a similar issue